# Session object changes when object is updated in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, session-variables

I have this really weird problem and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. I have these two lines:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[listModelType + "ListModel"] = listModel;
listModel.ProductRows = new Collection<ProductRow>(listModel.ProductRows.Where(r => r.ParentRowId == 0).ToList());
```

After the second line is executed my session object is updated as well (according to "Watch" in Visual Studio)

What am I missing here?

I have tried

```
int i = 0;
HttpContext.Current.Session["i"] = i;
i++;
```

and HttpContext.Current.Session["i"] remains 0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [value types and reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx).

The `int` is a value type so will be stored "as-is" on the moment of assignment; your `listModel` is a reference type so you store a reference to the object in your session, not the value of the object.

You'll have to create a new instance of `listModel` if you want the one in your session untouched.

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster - will give it a go. Just thought it was always the value that was stored.

Comment: your right with what you've thought, values are stored in sessions

Answer (score 4):

In your first example you are storing a reference to the object (The lists memory location).  So if the `list` is updated it will reflect in the session.  This is a reference type.

In the second example you are using a value type:

```
int i = 0;
HttpContext.Current.Session["i"] = i;
i++;
```

You declare `i` and set it to 0 (Value type)

You store the value `0` in the session. (Not the memory location of `i`)

You increment `i` but the session still has the value `0`

Comment: How does this work when the session is stored in SQL on a high availability setup. Does updating the list automatically trigger a save to the SQL server? Or is it just saved in some type of memory cache layer that would only be available on the current server? Does this mean that people that rely on code like OP posted would run into trouble if they switched to a HA / Sql backed session?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example your session variable is pointing to a `reference` so it gets updated because the two references are pointing to the same value.

The second session variable is pointing to a `primitive (value)` type so they have separate copies of value.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example your session variable is pointing to a reference so it gets updated because the two references are pointing to the same value.

so before assigning to the session you convert it into Json and then assign

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[listModelType + "ListModel"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listModel);
```

Note: JsonConvert is from name space Newtonsoft.Json namespace in c#

In second line if value changes in listModel object that does't reflect session.
but when you want to retreive the value from session you should convert to object form Json

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session[listModelType + "ListModel"] != null)
{

    listModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<*CLASS name of lsitmodel*>((string)HttpContext.Current.Session[listModelType + "ListModel"]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way should be:

```
  int i = 0;
  i++;
  HttpContext.Current.Session["i"] = i;
```

the *HttpContext.Current.Session["i"]* remains 1.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example your session variable is pointing to a reference so it gets updated because the two references are pointing to the same value.

so before assigning to the session you convert it into Json and then assign

```
   HttpContext.Current.Session[listModelType + "ListModel"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listModel);
```

Note: JsonConvert is from name space Newtonsoft.Json namespace in c#

In second line if value changes in listModel object that does't reflect session. but when you want to retreive the value from session you should convert to object form Json

```
   if (HttpContext.Current.Session[listModelType + "ListModel"] != null) {

        listModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<*CLASS name of lsitmodel*>((string)HttpContext.Current.Session[listModelType + "ListModel"]);

    }
```