# Asp.net,Session state issues with the following scenario

Tags: asp.net, mvp

Can any one help me out of the problem ,which I am facing by the sessions.

```
int a=5;

 HttpContext.Current.Session["Session_Variable"] = a;

 a = 0;
```

This is the Exact problem what I am facing.
First we are assigning the value 'a' to the session which contains the value as 5.
After that I make that 'a' as 0.
In this case the value which is stored in the session also effected to 0.

I tried which `Iproc` session as well as `OutProc(SqlServer session)`,Still issue Exist.

Thanks in Advance 
Adityap

Comment: Is that the exact code that you are using? Because that simply doesn't happen. The value of the variable `a` is copied when it's stored in the session variable as it's a value type, so changing the variable `a` doesn't affect the session varaible.

Comment: Hi @Guffa,Thanks for your quick reply.This is the exact scenario i am using but not the code.This is working fine if i use appfabric cache instead of the session.i am ready to provide more details if needed.Thank you

Comment: Provide more details : Is this set on page load  OR where? Show the complete function where this lines are present

Comment: hi @FlopScientist,This method is in the HTTPHANDLER(.cs).This is geting called from the jQuery ajax.

Comment: Hi Aditya, please show the full function where the above 3 lines are present

Comment: private void SavingIntoDB(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionConstants.PRODUCTLEVEL_PARTS] = productPart;

        productPart.Parts = null;
    }

Comment: @FlopScientist above is the code which is in the Handler method which i called from the jQuery ajax calls.if u need i will show u the ajax call code also

Comment: @Aditya is there got any error of null pointer with session ?? i mean object reference can not set an instance of an object ??

Comment: @Aditya  is this file of .ashx?

Comment: hi @BhavinChauhan id didnt get any null pointer exception and this handler file is .cs not the ashx.

Comment: @Aditya I don't know but I think session is not reference type variable so how you faced this issue:( i have face null pointer issue with ashx file and i have inherite IRequiresSessionState class and i solved issue

Comment: @Aditya post your code file I want to see http://pastie.org/

Comment: @BhavinChauhan my problem is similar to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484059/session-object-changes-when-object-is-updated-in-c-sharp

Comment: @BhavinChauhan actually i cant post the entire file(confidential issue withe the company),but can show u the exact code what i written.           private void SavingIntoDB(HttpContext context) { HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionConstants.PRODUCTLEVEL_PARTS] = productPart; productPart.Parts = null; }

Comment: @BhavinChauhan the above is called from the ajax call(from jQuery).i think my object which is storing in the DB is reference type.(as i tries with integer itsnt giving the issue)

Comment: @Aditya its ok if this is confidential and i understand your problem one another way is there if you want to pass the data between class. this is static class and static variable may be this will help you :)

Comment: @BhavinChauhan Actually my requirement is to store the values in the session.in this cases i am facing this problem

Answer (score 1):

The code that you showed in the comments is completely different from the code in the question.

The code in the question uses a value type, so assigning the value from the variable to the session variable will copy the value. Assigning another value to the variable will not affect the value that was copied to the session variable.

The code in the comments uses a reference type, so assigning the value from the variable to the session variable will copy the reference. That means that both the variable and the session variable are pointing to the same instance of the object. Also, the code in the comment changes a member of the object, it doesn't assign a new value to the variable.

When you change the member of the object that the variable is pointing to, it will change the object that the session variable is pointing to because it's the same object. It's not another copy of the object that looks the same, it's literally the same object.

If you want to put the object in the session variable and then be able to change the object without affecting the object that the session variable points to, you need to clone the object and put the copy in the session variable. If the object supports cloning you can use the `Clone` method, otherwise you need to create another instance of the object that has the same values as the original.

Comment: hi @Guffa,Thank you for your reply.as u said,i am facing problem with reference type only.i tried by creating new instance.but it didn't worked.i will try with cloning method.i am very thank full if u provide more details on cloning