# How to declare Independence variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to explain my summary code flow.

I have    `Session["MainRule"]`    and I call a method to get selected item from this =>

```
var temprule=get_temp_rule_byid(Session["MainRule"],id);
```

I put this `temprule` to `Session["temprule"]`.

Because when I update `Session["temprule"]`,I don't want to update Main Session `Session["MainRule"]`.

But When I was doing something update in `Session["temprule"].` why `Session["MainRule"]` value automatically change?

Update

```
var temprule= RulesRepository.get_temp_rule_byid(Session["MainRule"], id);


public static RuleViewModel get_temp_rule_byid(object rulesFromSession, string id)
        {
            RuleViewModel ruleViewModel = null;
            var temp = rulesFromSession as Dictionary<string, RuleViewModel>;
            if (temp?.TryGetValue(id, out ruleViewModel) == true)
            {
                return ruleViewModel;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Show the code for `get_temp_rule_byid`.

Comment: If a different session variable changes it's because your code did it. Post your code.

Comment: I suspect that if you replace `Session` with any other dictionary and try a unit test, you'll see the same behavior.

Comment: What is `temprule`? If this is an instance of a class and you store the _same instance_ in `Session["MainRule"]` and `Session["temprule"]`...well that _is_ the changed instance. Seems you want to store a _copy_ of the rule in `Session["temprule"]`.

Comment: @RenéVogt temprule is a temp session.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like value in your session is reference type.
[Session object changes when object is updated in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484059/session-object-changes-when-object-is-updated-in-c-sharp)

If you do not want the value to change clone the value before putting it in session.

Comment: ,Please can you explain more detail?

Comment: I pasted link from another question which explains it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484059/session-object-changes-when-object-is-updated-in-c-sharp